# how can I make a frame made with css be over a div and when changing the width does not affect the content of the div, only the width of the frame?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I want to know how I can make a frame I made with css be over a div and at the time of adjusting the width of the frame does not change the width of the div?

I attached an image with an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRO8p.png)  of what I want to do and my html and css

```css
.color {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E65959;
}
.shape {
  float: auto;
  z-index: -1 height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="shape">
  <section id="QueEsIAM">
    <div class="container color" id="fondoIm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <h2 class="section-heading titulos">TITLE</h2>
          <p class="subs">Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4">
          <a href="" class="ov">
            <img src="https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/osx/preview_icon_mul.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="" class="iconos">
          </a>
          <h4 class="service-heading">Subtitle</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <a href="">
            <img src="https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/osx/preview_icon_mul.png" width="200px" height="200px" alt="" class="iconos">
          </a>
          <h4 class="service-heading">Subtitle2</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @karthick nagarajan

Comment: You Welcome@NellyDesu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
<style>
.color {
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #E65959;
  padding:2%;
}
.shape {

  height: 100%;
  width: 96%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding:2%;
}
.hide-border{
   position: relative;
  background-color: #E65959;
  height:4px;
  z-index:1;
  width:40%;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:2px
}
</style>    
<div class="color">
  <div class="hide-border">

  </div>
  <div class="shape">
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the , when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make  a type specimen book.
  </div>
</div>
```